# Code won't stop running. Seems trivial but I cannot figure it out

Tags: python, python-3.5

Here's my code for approximating exp(x).  I know there's probably a function for factorial but I wanted to make sure I could create one myself :)

```
def factorial(n):
    """Computes factorial of a number n"""
    fac = n
    while n != 1:
        fac = fac * (n-1)
        n -= 1
    return fac


def exp_x_approx(x, n):
    """estimates exp(x) using a taylor series with n+1 terms"""
    s = 0
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        s = s + ((x**i)/factorial(i))
        print (s)
    return s

print(exp_x_approx(2,8))
```

There's no error until I ^c to stop it from running, at which point it reads:

```
File "/Users/JPagz95/Documents/exp_x_approx.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(exp_x_approx(2,8))
  File "/Users/JPagz95/Documents/exp_x_approx.py", line 13, in exp_x_approx
    s = s + ((x**i)/factorial(i))
  File "/Users/JPagz95/Documents/exp_x_approx.py", line 5, in factorial
    fac = fac * (n-1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I believe it's endlessly looping but I cannot figure out why.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can we please see your factorial function

Comment: factorial function tested out correct so I don't think the problem is there

Comment: I think the problem is with factorial 0

Comment: Since it is actually going negative on n

Comment: Your range function is going from 0 to n+1

Comment: If you do a while n >= 1, I think it might fix it? But you would be doing division with 0 when it reaches 0.

Comment: yeah despite initial thoughts the factorial was the problem.  Fixed it as explained below.  Thanks for the help guys

Comment: @JordanPagni You should vote up and mark the answer as fixed so those guys who helps you gets credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function

```
def factorial(n):
   """Computes factorial of a number n"""
   fac = n
   while n != 1:
       fac = fac * (n-1)
       n -= 1
   return fac
```

You can modify it like this

```
def factorial(n):
    if n < 0:
        return "some error info."
    fac = 1
    while n>=1:
        fac = fac * n
        n -= 1
    return fac
```

You should set your initial condition as fac=1 and set you terminate condition as n>=1 rather than n!=1. Think about what if I give a number -2?

Comment: thanks for your help! makes more sense looking back on it

Comment: The factorial of zero is 1.

Answer (score 1):

your first call to the factorial(i) function is called with i=0. factorial look is while(n!=0) ..... n=n-1.   You start of at 0 and keep lowering it by 1, so the loop never reaches 1 and stops.

Comment: thanks i just figured that out and fixed it by putting a if n = 0 return 1 statement in the factorial function! :)